# iOS 11, iPhone X. UIScrollView bounces in a wrong direction when setting contentOffset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have an issue with UIScrollView on iPhone X, iOS 11.2 (simulator)

I have noticed that it happens if I don't set `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`.

I want to implement a simple animation of scrolling elements up and sliding another element inside. Apparently when I change `contentOffset` animatedly to value `(0, 546)` I get a little bounce (check image):

[image: incorrect behaviour]

Which seems to be confirmed by logs:

```
scrollToBottom: insets top: 0.00; bottom: 74.00; left: 0.00; right: 0.00;
scrollToBottom: yPos 546.0
scrollToBottom: contentSize(375.0, 1240.0) self.height 768.0
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 496.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 486.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 487.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 489.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 491.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 494.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 498.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 501.666666666667)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 506.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 510.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 514.333333333333)
```

As you can see there are around 10 units bounce at the beginning 496 -> 486 -> and now increasing.

If (with exactly the same code) I insert larger element - everything is fine (check image):

[image: normal behaviour]

And logs:

```
scrollToBottom: insets top: 0.00; bottom: 214.00; left: 0.00; right: 0.00;
scrollToBottom: yPos 826.0
scrollToBottom: contentSize(375.0, 1380.0) self.height 768.0
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 498.666666666667)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 506.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 518.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 534.666666666667)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 555.0)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 578.666666666667)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 604.666666666667)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 632.333333333333)
scrollViewDidScroll: contentOffset (0.0, 661.0)
```

The code for this is rather simple: setup initial elements, set content offset, get delegate call about finished animation, slide in new element.

It seems if I turn off content inset adjustment behaviour it doesn't occur, but in that case I have to deal with insets myself. This seems not to happen on iPhone 6 with iOS 11.1.

Do you have any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The problem was in a combination of `contentSize` and `contentOffset` calculation on iPhone X.

I was calculating offset and then recalculating `contentSize`. There was a discrepancy in "new" `contentSize` and so when I was trying to scroll (`setContentOffset(_:animated:)`) I was simultaneously changing `contentSize` slightly (for 10 points which you can see in logs) and getting the bounce effect.

Apparently for larger scrolling distance 10 points were not that significant and so they were "interpolated" away.

Answer (score 0):

Just set ContentInsets - Automatic for scrollView\tableView